# BSD Sockets ip6 inet_pton and how to retrieve the scope ID

Tags: c++, c, sockets, bsd

I am currently working on an IPv6 class and use inet_pton to retrieve the actual binary representation of the IP from a string i.e.:

```
    AdressV6::AdressV6(const String & _ip)
    {
        int result = inet_pton(AF_INET6, _ip.c_str(), &(m_nativeAdress));

        if(result <= 0)
            //throw...

        //How can I retrieve the sope ID from that?
    }
```

Is there a common way to do that? Do you just manually parse the string and look for the "%"  that does not sound very bullet proof :(

Thank you!

I tried manual parsing for now which seems to work. Still, if there is a better way please let me know:

```
        //retrieve scope ID
        uint32 scopeId = 0;
        size_t pos = _ip.find("%");
        if(pos != String::npos)
        {
            String theId = _ip.substr(pos+1);
            scopeId = atoi(theId.c_str());
        }
        m_scopeId = scopeId;
```

Comment: Your scan code is broken, it assumes that scope ID is a number. While %1 or %2 are valid scope IDs, their meaning is completely implementation dependent. Scope IDs can also be interface names, like %dc0, %eth0 or %en0 (depending on how the OS in use names interfaces). See my reply for details how to get correct scope IDs, even for those that are interface names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On BSD and BSD based systems (this includes MacOS X for example), the scope ID is embedded into the address itself for link local addresses as the second 16 bit word. Please refer to the [FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/ipv6.html) and search for "8.1.1.3 Scope Index" (without the quotes).

So assuming that intf1 has scope ID 1 and intf2 has scope ID 2, `inet_pton()` will convert the strings as follows on these platforms:

```
"fe80::1234%intf1" -> fe80:1::1234
"fe80::1234%intf2" -> fe80:2::1234
"fe80::1234"       -> fe80::1234
```

The last address is simply unscoped and thus cannot be really used for sending out data.

Please note that this is non-standard; `inet_pton()` does not work that way on Linux or Windows based systems. However, I think even on Linux and Windows based systems, `inet_pton()` allows a scope ID at the end, it will simply ignore it, though.

For non-link-local address, this trick doesn't work, of course, yet those addresses are usually not scoped. They can be scoped, but usually every interface has an own, unique interface IPv6 address, based on its interface identifier (even if you use DHCPv6, in which case it has a DHCP address assigned by the DHCP server, as well as the auto generated IPv6 interface address, unless this auto generation has been forbidden).

The `struct sockaddr_in6` structure has a field for the scope ID but the RFC that defines this field ([RFC 2553 - Section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2553#section-3.3)) does not really give much detail how this field is to be interpreted. It only says:

> The mapping of sin6_scope_id to an interface or set of interfaces is
> left to implementation and future specifications on the subject of
> site identifiers.

So this field is entirely implementation specific.

If you want this field to be filled in correctly, and your code should be as cross-platform as possible, you should use `getaddrinfo()`:

```
struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo * result;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
// AI_NUMERICHOST prevents usage of DNS servers,
// it tells getaddrinfo that the input string is a numeric IP address.
hints.flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
if (getaddrinfo("fe80::1234%intf1", NULL, &hints, &result) == 0) {
    // result->ai_addr claims to be a pointer to struct sockaddr,
    // in fact it will be a pointer to a struct sockaddr_in6 in our case.
    struct sockaddr_in6 * so = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)result->ai_addr;

    // It will be prefilled like this:
    //
    // so->sin6_family   ==> AF_INET6;
    // so->sin6_port     ==> 0
    // so->sin6_flowinfo ==> 0
    // so->sin6_addr     ==> fe80::1234
    // so->sin6_scope_id ==> "intf1" as scope ID
    
    // Do something with that sockaddr,
    // e.g. set a port number and connect a socket to that address.

    freeaddrinfo(result);
}
```

One extra tip: If you want to use the returned `getaddrinfo()` for a server socket (a socket that you want to bind locally and then call `accept()` on it), you should also set the passive flag:

```
hints.flags = AI_NUMERICHOST | AI_PASSIVE;
```

Not that it will play a role in most case but that is the correct way of using `getaddrinfo()`.

Comment: Regarding the embedded scope IDs: they are an internal representation and are not meant to be visible outside the kernel on BSD/Darwin. Rather few APIs expose them, and they will eventually be fixed. ioctls and sysctls are the only common ways you'll get hold of an address with embedded scope-id; otherwise, userland functions and code should work with the correct use of sockaddr_in6 where possible.

Comment: @NicholasWilson They may not be meant to be visible outside the kernel, yet they are visible at the time being; I can even confirm that for the latest version of OS X. Despite the fact that on OS X even the UI displays those addresses with embedded scope ID (e.g. the network preferences do so, if you only have a link local IPv6 address). So a user who knows nothing about those addresses may accidentally copy&paste one from there and as a consequence, all functions that are supposed to deal with IPv6 address strings do handle embedded scope correctly on OS X.

Comment: That's pretty poor of the network preferences app. It's probably just calling getifaddrs, which is one of the few libc functions that still exposes the embedded scope id (and it's implemented with an ioctl on Darwin [or was]; the fact that it doesn't reformat the address that's copied to it out of the kernel is indeed a bug). It could be worse: on some broken systems, getaddrinfo prints addresses without appending the scope id (bad bad bug) and SunOS gets mixed up with scope ids for aliased interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

`inet_pton()` does not support scope IDs.  I don't know about other platforms, but on Windows you can use [`RtlIpv6StringToAddressEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814463.aspx) instead.

Comment: ty, I am not on windows though. The manual parsing seems to work for now, even though it requires to use a specific ipv6 notation.

Answer (score 0):

`inet_pton()` semi-supports scope identifiers, the scope is that it will not raise an error when parsing an address with one.  The major limitation is that the parameter to the call is a `struct in6_addr` which does not contain a field for the scope identifier, the super structure `struct sockaddr_in6` is required for that.

Easy way forward is to wrap `getnameinfo()` and `getaddrinfo()` with `struct sockaddr` parameters for convenience.  For example,

```
socklen_t
sockaddr_len (
        const struct sockaddr*  sa
        )
{
        socklen_t sa_len;
        switch (sa->sa_family) {
        case AF_INET:   sa_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in); break;
        case AF_INET6:  sa_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6); break;
        default:        sa_len = 0; break;
        }
        return sa_len;
}

int
sockaddr_ntop (
        const struct sockaddr* restrict sa,
        char*                  restrict host,
        size_t                          hostlen
        )
{
        return getnameinfo (sa, sockaddr_len (sa),
                            host, hostlen,
                            NULL, 0,
                            NI_NUMERICHOST);
}

int
sockaddr_pton (
        const char*      restrict src,
        struct sockaddr* restrict dst           /* will error on wrong size */
        )
{
        struct addrinfo hints = {
                .ai_family      = AF_UNSPEC,
                .ai_socktype    = SOCK_STREAM,          /* not really */
                .ai_protocol    = IPPROTO_TCP,          /* not really */
                .ai_flags       = AI_NUMERICHOST
        }, *result = NULL;
        const int status = getaddrinfo (src, NULL, &hints, &result);
        if (0 == status) {
                memcpy (dst, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
                freeaddrinfo (result);
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

To answer the original premise but given a `struct sockaddr`, an additional API may be warranted, for example:

```
uint32_t
sockaddr_scope_id (
        const struct sockaddr*  sa
        )
{
        uint32_t scope_id;
        if (AF_INET6 == sa->sa_family) {
                struct sockaddr_in6 s6;
                memcpy (&s6, sa, sizeof(s6));
                scope_id = s6.sin6_scope_id;
        } else
                scope_id = 0;
        return scope_id;
}
```